# Concave function properties

Tags: geometry, functions

Given a concave function $f(x)$, $\,f(x)$ decreases as $\,x\,$ increases.

That is,  $\;f(x_1)\gt f(x_2)\,$ if $\,x_2\gt x_1$

For $\;f(x_1)+f(x_2)\;$ and $\;\large\left(\frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{2}\right)^2,\;$ which one is larger?

For $\;(1-f(x_1))(1-f(x_2))\;$ and $\;1\large-\left(\frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{2}\right)^2,\;$ which one is larger?

Is there any theorem to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Not all concave functions satisfy what you have written in your first sentence. Do you assume you have such a concave function?

Comment: Be careful! $\log x$ (or $\ln x$) is concave, but increasing.

Comment: @LordSoth: Yes, I assume it is a decreasing function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, for both problems, is that either might be larger; i.e. there is not enough information.

Take $f_k(x)=-x+k$.  This is a concave, decreasing, function, as specified in the problem.

First, $f_k(0)+f_k(1)=2k-1$, while $\left(\frac{f_k(0+1)}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)^2$.
For $k=0$, the latter is larger; for $k=1$, the former is larger.

Second, $(1-f_k(0))(1-f_k(1))=k^2-3k+2$, while $1-\left(\frac{f_k(0+1)}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{1}{2}k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}$.  For $k=0$, the former is larger; for $k=1$, the latter is larger.